# Cannot find org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, aspectj

I'm setting a Spring 3.2.3 + Hibernate 4 project in Eclipse 4.3.

When I add the code `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>` to my context I start getting the following error in every single bean:

```
Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
```

Now, I added both AspectJ Tools and Cglib dependencies to my project and the JARs are there, including the class it can't find. The application runs normally, and Spring is managing sessions and transactions successfully.

I've searched for a solution but every answers says the error occurs because the lack of JARs.

Does anyone knows what I'm missing (incompatible versions?) or is this an Eclipse bug?

Here is a print screen of the problem (every error you'll see is the one I indicated above).

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the solution to my problem!

When I installed the Spring Tools plugin it seems I forgot to check both "AspectJ Compiler" and "AspectJ Development Tools" from the plugin list. As soon as I installed and restarted the Eclipse, the errors disappeared.

Here's a print screen if someone interested:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you're missing som aspectj libs?

Try adding to your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>    
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I had same issue using spring-aop 3.2.8. This class is actually inside org.aspectj.aspectjweaver artifact, but I was using wrong version 1.7.4

Comment: if you are working with sts,plsease add this dependency also along with above two(if not added)                                                         <dependency>
     <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
 </dependency>

Answer (score 3):

Here's what worked for me:

- I added to my POM.xml the dependencies Pere suggested in his answer:

  org.aspectj
      aspectjrt
      1.7.3


      org.aspectj
      aspectjweaver
      1.7.3

Then I right clicked on my project's name in Project Explorer --> properties --> java build path --> Order and Export tab.

In this tab I noticed that for some strange reason Maven Dependencies is no longer checked.
I checked it, and after I applied the changes, the error mentioned in the question above disappeared.

Comment: this answer Solved my Problem as STS shows error on all of my bean classes. But the project runs without any errors. Just did this to remove errors from the xml file. Did'nt add any extra dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the Spring builder to my eclipse .project file to fix this issue

```
        <buildCommand>
        <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
```

Answer (score 0):

I received this same error message when copying xml code from an older project. I believe the relevant
line in the `<beans` header that was causing the problem was:
   `http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd`
as the project had been/was actually using the 4.0 libraries.

To fix it I deleted the offending xml file,
used right click to remove spring project nature (under spring tools), closed/reopened the project.
Once the error was gone, I converted back to spring nature and then recreated the xml file with
3.2 properly changed to 4.0.