# Spring AspectJ - ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException error

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

Alright, I've successfully done AOP through the XML file, but I am struggling with AspectJ. For some reason I cannot get this to work properly. I've looked online, anything I found seems to not work, not sure why.

here is my code

AspectJ.java:

```
@Aspect
public class AspectJ {

@Before("execution(* com.ibm..AnimalBean.*(..) )" )
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinpoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("AspectJ - Before " +     
joinpoint.getSignature().getName() );
}
}
```

TestClass (.java.):
        public class TestClass {
    AnimalBean testBean;

```
@Autowired
public void setTestBean(AnimalBean testBean) {
    this.testBean = testBean;
}

public void runTestClass(int id, String animal) {
    ApplicationContext jdbcContext = new 
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("jdbcContext.xml");
    AnimalDaoImpl animalDao = (AnimalDaoImpl)
jdbcContext.getBean("animalDaoImpl"); 

    testBean.setId(id);
    testBean.setTestAnimal(animal);
    System.out.println("setBean - id: "+testBean.getId()+" animal:
"+testBean.getTestAnimal());
    animalDao.createRow(testBean);
    testBean = new AnimalBean();
    this.testBean = animalDao.retrieveRow(testBean, 2);
    System.out.println("getBean - id: "+testBean.getId()+" animal:
"+testBean.getTestAnimal());
}
}
```

appContext.xml:

```
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`
    <bean id="myAnimalBean" class="com.ztp.spring.injection.AnimalBean" />
     <bean id="myAnimalBean" class="com.ztp.spring.injection.AnimalBean" /> <-- error
    <bean id="myTestClass" class="com.ztp.spring.injection.TestClass"> <--error
    <property name="testBean" ref="myAnimalBean" />
</bean>
<bean id="myAspectJ" class="com.ibm.spring.aspect.AspectJ" />
```

where the *** is an error comes up that says "Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException"

I also have three aspect jar files; aspectjrt-1.5.4.java, aspectjtools-1.6.1.java, aspectjweaver-1.7.0.java.

Am I missing something obvious here? Or is it something not-so-obvious? If this has been answered before, please inform me, I'd loved to finally solve this.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
i forgot to mention, i saw the post at "[Cannot find org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047775/cannot-find-org-aspectj-weaver-reflect-reflectionworld)" and they install AspectJ from the distribution "http://dist.spring

So I guess the question is, how do I install AspectJ? Answer if you'd like, I'm going to try Google.

SOLVED!!!!:
I solved the issue, and I will answer it here so this post can help others who are/were as lost as I was.
when installing Eclipse software, put in the address "http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/35/update", Its all the code for AspectJ.

Comment: This usually indicates that you aren't running the AspectJ piece of your build. How are you building your project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047775/cannot-find-org-aspectj-weaver-reflect-reflectionworld)