# Trying to learn Spring: BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, exception

Started to learn "Spring in Action" and got a trouble on the very first chapter.
I have simple Spring application, built with Maven:

`pom.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.alesto</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-study</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.41-beta</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have XML application context where I define three beans:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="knight" class="main.java.alesto.knight.BraveKnight">
        <constructor-arg ref="quest" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="quest" class="main.java.alesto.knight.SlayDragonQuest">
        <constructor-arg value="#{T(System).out}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="minstrel" class="main.java.alesto.knight.Minstrel">
        <constructor-arg value="#{T(System).out}" />
    </bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="minstrel">
            <aop:pointcut id="embark"
                          expression="execution(* *.embarkOnQuest(..))" />

            <aop:before pointcut-ref="embark"
                        method="singBeforeQuest"/>

            <aop:after pointcut-ref="embark"
                       method="singAfterQuest"/>
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
</beans>
```

As yo see I've tried to inject invocations of two particular methods `before` and `after` method whose id is **"embark"**. And exactly this part of code (aop) causes `BeanCreationException`:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'knight' defined in class path resource [main/resources/spring/knight.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7ea9e1e2' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7ea9e1e2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'embark' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embark': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:478)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at main.java.alesto.knight.KnightMain.main(KnightMain.java:7)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7ea9e1e2' of type [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJMethodBeforeAdvice] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7ea9e1e2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'embark' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embark': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:648)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:248)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:988)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:959)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7ea9e1e2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'embark' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embark': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embark': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1105)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1050)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:80)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 48 more
```

Here are `beans` themselves:
**Knight who embarks on quest**:

```
package main.java.alesto.knight;

public class BraveKnight implements Knight {

    private Quest quest;

    //We are going to inject a quest via Spring using CONSTRUCTOR INJECTION
    public BraveKnight(Quest quest) {
        this.quest = quest;
    }

    public void embarkOnQuest() {
        quest.embark();
    }
}
```

**Quest itself**:

```
package main.java.alesto.knight;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public class SlayDragonQuest implements Quest {

    private PrintStream stream;

    //We are going to inject a quest via Spring using CONSTRUCTOR INJECTION
    public SlayDragonQuest(PrintStream stream) {
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public void embark() {
        stream.println("Embarking on quest to slay the dragon!");
    }
}
```

**And minstrel assosiated with knight and who sings songs depending on knight's actions**:

```
package main.java.alesto.knight;

import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Minstrel {

    private PrintStream printStream;

    public Minstrel(PrintStream printStream) {
        this.printStream = printStream;
    }

    public void singBeforeQuest() {
        printStream.println("This piece of shit is going to dieeeeee!!11");
    }

    public void singAfterQuest() {
        printStream.println("The noble hero brought the victory!");
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this exception and how to solve it?

Comment: You are missing the maven dependancies for AOP (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.2.4.RELEASE). See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047775/cannot-find-org-aspectj-weaver-reflect-reflectionworld

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting is:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException

This means that your application is missing a required library. In your case, you are doing AOP with Spring (`<aop:config>`) so you need to add Spring AOP to your Maven POM:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

---

As a side-note, I notice that you are depending on Mockito and JUnit with the default `compile` scope. Since those are probably test dependencies, it would be better to declare them with the `test` scope:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
    <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.41-beta</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately samples in the book have built with Gradle and I am not familiar with it.
Though, your advice didn't help completely. Considering your advice I had also to add dependency for "spring-aspects".
Only then it went right.

Answer (score 1):

add reference for cglib as following for gradle:
compile group: 'cglib', name: 'cglib', version: '3.2.5'
then run gradle build in command line, then run the program, everything will be ok!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. Solution: You need the AspectJ library.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```